# Multiple instances of a GLB mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create an asteroid field and would like to load the same simple rock model once and then use this instance a few hundred times while randomly adjusting position, rotation and size. I have the model as a .glb file, and I was able to import it once fine, and even import it inside of a loop to get the result, but it was slow as hell. So I'm attempting to use instancing to make it work, but I'm stuck.

I worked off of [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_performance), and as long as I use their JSON file it's okay. I'm stuck trying to import the .glb instead of .json. I would like to keep the material from the glb as well.

```js
function initMesh() {

    let geometry, material;

    loader.load(
        modelsFolder + 'rock.glb',
        function (gltf) {

            material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            geometry = gltf.scene.children[0];
            makeInstanced(geometry, material, 20);

        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            // load progress
            // console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( error ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened', error );
        }
    );
}

function makeInstanced( geometry, material, instanceCount ) {

    const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    const mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, instanceCount );

    for ( let i = 0; i < instanceCount; i ++ ) {

        randomizeMatrix( matrix );
        mesh.setMatrixAt( i, matrix );

    }

    scene.add( mesh );

}

const randomizeMatrix = function () {

    const position = new THREE.Vector3();
    const rotation = new THREE.Euler();
    const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const scale = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function ( matrix ) {

        position.x = Math.random() * 40 - 20;
        position.y = Math.random() * 40 - 20;
        position.z = Math.random() * 40 - 20;

        rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

        quaternion.setFromEuler( rotation );

        scale.x = scale.y = scale.z = Math.random() * 1;

        matrix.compose( position, quaternion, scale );

    };

}();
```

Comment: You're right, you were experiencing slow framerate due to the number of drawcalls, and instancing is the solution. [This example draws 1000 Susannes](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_dynamic) very efficiently through instancing. You should look at the source code in this example to copy its methodology (in the bottom-right `<>` icon).

Comment: Thanks. I did follow a very similar example. My only problem is that all of those use JSON for model files and I have a GLB. There's probably a way to convert it to a JSON and then use that, but I'd like to keep my current textures that are in the GLB as well.